# Rsync Specific Listed Files from specified Server Directory

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I'd like to rsync specified files from a specific server folder to my local directory (in which I am running the command).

However, I'm getting the error failed: No such file or directory (2).  There seems to be something wrong with my syntax and I'm not sure its picking up the source directory properly

This is my command...

```
rsync -az . remoteSite.com::remoteFolder/remoteSubFolder/ --files-from=filelist.txt
```

filelist.txt, which it seems to be finding, contains filenames within remoteSubFolder

```
file1.xml
file2.xml
etc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're transferring from the remote server to the local directory, you have the source and destination parameters backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gordon Davisson.

I now understand that the full stop represents the local directory and goes after the remote host and directory.

```
rsync -az --files-from=filelist.txt remoteSite.com::remoteFolder/remoteSubFolder/ .
```